What Cherry MX mechanical keyboard switch is closest to an Apple Extended Keyboard II?
I would like to buy a mechanical keyboard, but even after using a mechanical keyboard switch tester to try out different types of switches, I can't determine which one I like the best (other than that I don't want a switch that makes a loud 'click' sound). (†)
The switch tester I'm using is this one - it has 9 different Cherry MX switches: Cherry MX Red, Cherry MX Black, Cherry MX Blue, Cherry MX Brown, Cherry MX Green,
Cherry MX Gray (black), Cherry MX Clear, Cherry MX White, and "Speed Silver" (?).
I spent many years in the 1990s using an Apple Extended Keyboard II, which I don't remember dropping keystrokes like my current Apple Magic keyboard. Can anyone tell me which switch is closest to the switch used in an Apple Extended Keyboard II?
† Business opportunity: A 'keyboard petting zoo'.

The question as currently written "Can anyone tell me which switch is closest to the switch used in an Apple Extended Keyboard II?" means you think that (a) there's a list somewhere of switches in order of 'closeness' to an Apple keyboard switch and (b) someone here has the list and can tell you the top entry on it. There obviously isn't any of that and this can only be a pure opinion question. Voting to close for that reason, I'm afraid.

I suggest you try asking on the Apple community message boards, where such questions are probably more appropriate (and more likely to get a number of answers).

The Apple Magic keyboard should not be dropping keystrokes.  Is this an issue with how you type on a flat keyboard with a very short stroke, or is the bluetooth connection not very good?

I think it's due to how I type on the keyboard - I have owned several Apple Magic Keyboards over the years, used with several different MacBooks, and when I notice a keystroke being 'dropped' it's almost always when I might have fumbled a keypress, and doesn't correspond to (rare) instances of the bluetooth connection being dropped. That's one reason why I wanted to try a mechanical keyboard - I figure the extra effort in using a 'proper' keyboard that isn't flat/low travel will force my typing style to change for the better.
